# Creating a new column if a condition is satisfied in the last N days python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

| timestamp | value | id. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-16 | 25 | 1 |
| 2020-12-17 | 45 | 1 |
| 2020-12-31 | 40 | 1 |
| 2021-01-31 | 37 | 1 |
| 2020-12-15 | 12 | 2 |
| 2020-12-16 | 78. | 2. |

I want to create a new column `outcome` which takes a value `yes` is the `id` doesn't have any entry for the last 25 days.
For e.g., this is the expected output

| timestamp | value | id. | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-16 | 25 | 1 | yes |
| 2020-12-17 | 45 | 1 | yes. |
| 2020-12-31 | 40 | 1 | yes. |
| 2021-01-31 | 37 | 1 | no. |
| 2020-12-15 | 12 | 2 | yes. |
| 2020-12-16 | 78. | 2. | yes. |

In the above example, we can assume that the start date is `2020-12-15`. So, our comparisons start after this date for all the `id`s.
For `id 1`, starting from `2020-12-15`, it has entries in the `last 25 days` except for `2021-01-31`. The entry that happened before `2021-01-31` is on `2020-12-31` which is `> 25 days` in this example. So, the `outcome` variable takes a value `no`. For the rest of the rows, it is `yes` because for each of the dates, there's a prior entry that falls within the 25 day difference.

I am very confused about how to write an algorithm for this.

I would have to `groupby` `id`, `order by` `timestamp` and then do `rolling` something on the `timestamp` to create the `outcome` column?

I am very confused about this and any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your calculation requires sorting we can avoid grouping. Sort, take a row-difference and use `where` to `NaN` the values that cross groups (i.e. the earliest row for every ID). Because you want the first difference to be relative to `'2020-12-15'` we can use `fillna` to find the difference from that date and use `np.where` to assign your strings values based on your condition.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'timestamp'])

s = (df['timestamp'].diff()
       .where(df['id'].eq(df['id'].shift()))
       .fillna(df['timestamp'] - pd.to_datetime('2020-12-15')))
#0    1 days
#1    1 days
#2   14 days
#3   31 days
#4    0 days
#5    1 days

df['outcome'] = np.where(s <= pd.Timedelta(25, 'D'), 'yes', 'no')
#   timestamp  value  id outcome
#0 2020-12-16     25   1     yes
#1 2020-12-17     45   1     yes
#2 2020-12-31     40   1     yes
#3 2021-01-31     37   1      no
#4 2020-12-15     12   2     yes
#5 2020-12-16     78   2     yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply conditions IF;

1.the difference between consecutive days in a group is less than 15
OR
2. The first item in a group are equal to yes. Any other elements not meeting any of the conditions equal no.

```
import numpy as np
df['outcome']=np.where(df.groupby('id.')['timestamp'].transform('diff').dt.days.lt(15)|~df['id.'].duplicated(keep='first'),'yes','no')



 timestamp  value  id. outcome
0 2020-12-16   25.0  1.0     yes
1 2020-12-17   45.0  1.0     yes
2 2020-12-31   40.0  1.0     yes
3 2021-01-31   37.0  1.0      no
4 2020-12-15   12.0  2.0     yes
5 2020-12-16   78.0  2.0     yes
```